# I have an error after installation of Ubuntu 12.04 in display

Tags: dual-boot

display is red totally and it shows that out of range.I had installed ubuntu with wubi

Comment: have a look to the answers of this [question](http://askubuntu.com/q/162075/32413)

Answer (score 0):

I would advice not to install ubuntu with wubi. But since you did, delete it. Install ubuntu using a live-usb or dvd. When you install ubuntu with wubi it is not stable enough.